# Cache API and images from backend server in sw-precache with gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, caching, sw-precache

I'm very new to use sw-precache with gulp in my app. I've created web app done by angularjs and fetch information from our backend nodejs application. At that application, I've added `sw-precache` feature to make offline first application.

one of api from backend, company images will be embedded as follow:

```
https://www.myserver.com/api/getcompany

{"company": [
    {"id": 1, "img": "https://myserver.com/images/img.jpg"},
    {"id": 2, "img": "https://myserver.com/images/img.jpg"}
]}
```

Here is my coding to use `sw-preache` with gulp to generate service-worker file.

```
gulp.task('generate-service-worker', function(callback) {
  var path = require('path');
  var swPrecache = require('sw-precache');
  var rootDir = 'dist';

  swPrecache.write(path.join(rootDir, 'sw.js'), {
    staticFileGlobs: [rootDir + '/**/*.{js,html,css,png,jpg,gif}'],
    stripPrefix: rootDir,
    runtimeCaching: [{
      urlPattern: /^https:\/\/myserver.com\.com\/api/,
      handler: 'networkFirst'
    }, {
      urlPattern: /\/api\//,
      handler: 'fastest',
      options: {
          cache: {
            maxEntries: 10,
            name: 'api-cache-01'
          }
      }
    }]
  }, callback);
});
```

Please let me know above coding is correct way to cache API and please let me know how to cache images from URL in gulp file?

Answer (score 1):

Your two `urlPatterns`—`/^https:\/\/myserver.com\.com\/api/` and `/\/api\//`, look like they'd end up handling the same sort of requests (though the one listed first in the array will take precedence).

It sounds like you have two different types requests that you'd like to apply runtime caching logic to, so let's treat them separately.

First, for your `/api/` requests, figure out whether you're okay with a stale response (in which case, use `fastest`) or whether you always need a fresh response.

Second, for your `/image/` requests, figure out if you expect that image at a given URL will event change or not (if it won't change, use `cacheFirst`).

You'll end up with a configuration that looks something like:

```
runtimeCaching: [{
  urlPattern: new RegExp('/api/'),
  handler: 'fastest' // Alternatively, 'networkFirst'.
}, {
  urlPattern: new RegExp('/images/'),
  handler: 'cacheFirst', // Alternatively, 'fastest'.
  options: {
    cache: {
      maxEntries: 50, // Or whatever upper limit you want.
      name: 'images'
    }
  }
}]
```

Comment: our backend and frontend are different. backend url is https://www. myserver.com and frontend is https://www.myfrontend.com that's why \api\ can be workable?

Comment: `new RegExp('/api/')` will match any requests made to any server that contains `/api/` somewhere in the URL. If that's not what you want, then you could tailor that regular expression, but it *seems* to be close enough to what you want based on what you describe.